# Strange Root CA certificate in Windows Trusted Root CA Store

Tags: authentication, certificates, malware, man-in-the-middle

While reviewing Root CA certificates in Windows Trusted Root CA Store I came across a stange Root CA certificate with Issuer Desktop-XXXXXXX and Subject Desktop-XXXXXXX, enhanced key usage for server authentication and validity of bit less than 1000 years.
I wonder if anyone has seen such kind of Root CA certificate.
I have no idea what application could have added this certificate to Windows Trusted Root CA Store.
Hopefully it was not done by some malware ...
Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the plausible guess. However in my case the certificate was created by Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Service

Answer (score 1):

This certificate is automatically generated by Hyper-V Virtual Machine Manager. It is used to connect to VMs from Hyper-V console. If you have a Hyper-V in use, then you should leave it (if you delete, Hyper-V will re-create it again), otherwise you can safely delete it.

**Update:**
A decade ago I've researched the same topic and provided a PowerShell script which allows you to generate the cert with your own algorithms and keys: [https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/time-machine®-for-microsoft-hyper-v-server-mythbuster-rebirth.aspx](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/time-machine%C2%AE-for-microsoft-hyper-v-server-mythbuster-rebirth.aspx)

Regarding outdated crypto in default cert -- the code was developed back in 2008 (with the release of Windows Server 2008) and simply wasn't updated since then. The purpose of this is to provide basic security and then let admins to install production-grade cert if necessary.

The cert is installed in trusted store -- to allow cert trust for local connections (when you connect to VMs from local host).

Comment: I do use Hyper-V. Have deleted the certificate in question two days ago. It has hot re-appeared in the Trusted Root CA Store since then.
What I do not understand is:
1. why this certificate was installed in the Trusted ROOT CA Store?
2. why does it use algorithms which are insecure - sha1rsa for signature, rsa key length of 1024 bits?

Comment: I've updated my response.

Comment: @1000+ a short (or otherwise weak e.g. Debian-bad-random) key _in_ a root cert (if used) is a problem, but a weak signature _on_ it is not because the signature on the root cert has no effect whatever on trust. I'm sure I've seen this more than once either here or crypto (maybe both), but google finds me only https://superuser.com/questions/1122069/why-are-root-cas-with-sha1-signatures-not-a-risk .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you very much for the link provided with an excellent explanation on why sha1 signature on Root certificates is not a problem.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you very much for an explanation. I can confirm that in my case the certificate in question was created by Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Service. I am only very curious why such cerificates are installed in particular in Root CA store?

Comment: About trust store -- see last paragraph in my response.

Comment: the script provided in your article "Time Machine® for Microsoft Hyper-V Server — mythbuster rebirth" seems to install local host server certificate in the localmachine/my store, and not in Root CA store. So why Microsoft defaults to Root CA store?